# Facebook Live Video - Graph API to get Length of VOD

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-live-api

I use the Graph API to publish live videos of a user in my app.  I can retrieve details of that video with the videoId when the video is not live anymore, and I get a status of LIVE_STOPPED (and later I get a status of VOD).

So my question, is there any way to know the duration (length) of the video when it's over?

I tried to get the field length, but it's not available, and seconds_left returns 0.

Comment: _“I tried to get the field length, but it's not available”_ - not on the live video itself, no. But the live video has a field `video`, the documentation describes it as _“The inside video of the live video”_ - and that is a normal [`Video`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/#fields) object, and as such has a `length` property. (Not sure at which point that will contain a sensible value in this constellation though, you’d have to check.)

Comment: That is exactly what I needed.  I didn't understand that part of the video field.  You should make that an answer and I will mark it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to get the field length, but it's not available

Not on the live video itself, no. But the live video has a *field* `video`, the documentation describes it as “The inside video of the live video” - and that is a normal [Video](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/#fields) object, and as such has a length property.

(Not sure at which point that will contain a sensible value in this constellation though, you’d have to check.)

Comment: Thank you! I don't see length on videos. Was this deprecated?

Comment: @AliisaRoe it looks like they might have removed it by now.